# Difference between these 2 function calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

Getting some practice in with delegates specifically using the Func keyword and noticed that I can make the same function call in 2 different ways.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a SelectListItem
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="function">Function which retrieves the data to populate the list</param>
    /// <param name="key">The column name which contains the index/uniqueidentifier which is used to identify the object</param>
    /// <param name="displayText">Column name for the text that will appear on the dropdown list</param>
    /// <returns> A List of SelectListItem</returns>

    public static List<SelectListItem> CreateList<T>(Func<List<T>> function, string key, string displayText)
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var model = function();
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var property = item.GetType().GetProperty(key);
            var text = item.GetType().GetProperty(displayText);
            if (property != null && text != null)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = text.GetValue(item, null).ToString(),
                    Value = property.GetValue(item, null).ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public  List<TestClass> GetList()
    {
        List<TestClass> test = new List<TestClass>();
        var t = new TestClass
        {
            Name = "T",
            Description = "P"
        };
        test.Add(t);
        return test;
    }

}
```

Called like:

```
var obj = new TestClass();

TestClass.CreateList(() => obj.GetList(), "Name", "Description");
TestClass.CreateList(obj.GetList, "Name", "Description");
```

Is there any difference between the way they are called? They both seem to run in the exact same way, are there efficiency differences between them?
Explanation would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument calls for a function.

This passes the function.

```
TestClass.CreateList(obj.GetList, "Name", "Description");
```

This passes an anonymous function that calls the function.

```
TestClass.CreateList(() => obj.GetList(), "Name", "Description");
```

The additional syntax of the second one is unnecessary. Resharper will offer to replace the second one with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are passing `Lambda expression`, while in the second one  `function` to `delegate`. No there is no difference in efficience.

> The => token is called the lambda operator. It is used in lambda
>   expressions to separate the input variables on the left side from the
>   lambda body on the right side. Lambda expressions are inline
>   expressions similar to anonymous methods but more flexible; they are
>   used extensively in LINQ queries that are expressed in method syntax
>   Source [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator)
>
> A delegate is a reference type that can be used to encapsulate a named
>   or an anonymous method. Delegates are similar to function pointers in
>   C++; however, delegates are type-safe and secure. For applications of
>   delegates, see Delegates and Generic Delegates.
>   Source [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate)

You can read about this differences here [delegates-actions-funcs-lambdaskeeping-it-super-simple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/03/02/c-delegates-actions-funcs-lambdaskeeping-it-super-simple/)